# Keybinding for auto-formatting properties in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there a keybinding in VS which allows properties to be formatted between the following two styles?

```
public string Property
{
    get { return "Daniel"; }
}
```

and

```
public string Property { get { return "Daniel"; } }
```

For instance, when autofilling an override Visual Studio will use the top example. I want to be able to highlight the property, hit a keybinding and have it automatically format using the second example.

Alternatively is there any way to configure Visual Studio so it only uses the bottom method? I've tweaked a few settings under Options > C# > Formatting but with no luck.

I realise it's a minor pet peeve, but I'd really like the functionality.

Comment: No that is not possible. VS has only a few formatting options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CodeMaid](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) extension for Visual Studio allows you to [join](http://www.codemaid.net/documentation/#joining) required lines of code into a single line.

Just select the code and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much! I would upvote your answer, but I'm afraid I don't have enough points to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You may try your luck here, this should be all keybindings of vs.
http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/